# Ubuntu server as DHCP server for dual stack

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, ipv6

I currently have an Ubuntu server on VirtualBox set up to give hosts on my GNS3 topology IPv4 addresses, and it is working without issues. However, I would like to have that same DHCP server give out IPv6 addresses as well at the same time, and I am not quite sure how to accomplish that. I have drawn a rough sketch of what my network looks like.

[image: Rough Network Topology]

I have done topologies with only IPv4 in the past and they have worked like a charm; however, I am learning IPv6 and there doesn't seem to be much material out there on DHCP and dual stacking from what I have been able to gather. Any help would be appreciated. The network I am working on will eventually expand, and I will most likely use OSPF as the routing protocol. Any help is appreciated, please let me know if my explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: Are you sure you need DHCPv6 on your network? IPv6 can do autoconfiguratoin without needing DHCPv6. You just need to enable router advertisements on `Router 2` and `Router 3` and have them each announced a `/64` prefix to their respective LANs.

Comment: @kasperd

I have read that it can be done (never actually tried it), but I would like to have a dedicated DHCPv6 server giving Host(1) an IPv6 addr instead, just to see how it works. 

Then I would like to have Router 2 and Router 3 set up as DHCP servers giving their respective hosts an IPv6 address as well.

Do you know where I could find the commands I need to accomplish my task? If they were to be explained in detailed it would be nice as well, I don't want to just copy and paste commands.

Also, forget about what I said about providing both IPV4 and IPv6 to those machines.

Comment: I just want to give those 3 hosts an IPv6 address in the way I described above.

Thank you

Comment: I know how to set up router advertisements and how to get auto configuration working with just router advertisements. And I absolutely recommend getting that working first before considering DHCPv6. As far as I know DHCPv6 without router advertisements is not a supported configuration. And you may even find clients without DHCPv6 support.